# Why is "group by" not working for MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the below query where I join two tables, the query is working when I remove the group by at the end, but it returns too many rows for me.

The first priority is to have the `order by` distance (which is calculated within the query), subsequently I want only the unique `tr_id` with the smallest distance.

When I use `group by` I get the following error:

> *1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `GROUP BY tr_id LIMIT 0, 30` at line 2.*

```
SELECT op.operatorid AS tr_id, de.latitude AS
tolatitude, de.longitude AS tolongitude, de.surname AS tosurname,
de.firstname AS tofirstname, de.did AS to_id,
de.tzz AS tmzz, 
op.bkk AS tobkk, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(52.524368165134284) ) * cos( radians(
de.latitude )
 ) * cos( radians( de.longitude) - radians(13.410530090332031) ) + sin(
radians(52.524368165134284) ) * sin( radians( de.latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance 
FROM de 
INNER JOIN op ON de.did = op.did 
WHERE de.type='Dutch' AND de.longitude > 11.6118868785
AND de.longitude < 15.2091733022 AND de.latitude > 50.7257249533
AND de.latitude < 54.323011377 having distance < 200 
GROUP BY tr_id
ORDER BY distance
```

Comment: I still don't see `LIMIT`. The query without `LIMIT` cannot show that error

Comment: @zerkms there is no limit in the query, but I ran the query in phpmyadmin which shows rows 0,30 I think that's why it showed in the error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HAVING clause must come after any GROUP BY clause,so your query must be:-

```
SELECT op.operatorid AS tr_id, de.latitude AS
tolatitude, de.longitude AS tolongitude, de.surname AS tosurname,
de.firstname AS tofirstname, de.did AS to_id,
de.tzz AS tmzz, 
op.bkk AS tobkk, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(52.524368165134284) ) * cos( radians(
de.latitude )
) * cos( radians( de.longitude) - radians(13.410530090332031) ) + sin(
radians(52.524368165134284) ) * sin( radians( de.latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance 
FROM de 
INNER JOIN op ON de.did = op.did 
WHERE de.type='Dutch' AND de.longitude > 11.6118868785
AND de.longitude < 15.2091733022 AND de.latitude > 50.7257249533
AND de.latitude < 54.323011377  
GROUP BY tr_id having distance < 200
ORDER BY distance
```

Comment: Thanks a lot user1163513! Works perfect

Answer (score 4):

`ORDER BY` should be specified **after** `GROUP BY`

PS: I don't see aggregate functions usage in your `SELECT`, so the whole query looks a bit confusing

Comment: @BastiaanWW: update your question with **new** version then. Btw I see the `LIMIT` clause in error, but not in the query